# Azure SQL Database for collecting app metrics limitations?

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, metrics

I'm writing a Windows desktop application in which I want to collect anonymous usage statistics.  I have set up an Azure SQL database and am connecting and writing data using SQL ADO.NET.  However, I have a couple of concerns.

1)  Is there a limit to how many users can simultaneously be using the same login for saving the data?
2)  Azure requires that I set up Firewall rules to prevent unauthorized users from accessing the database.  Is there any reason why I shouldn't set up a rule to cover all IP addresses since I don't know ahead of time the IP addresses of my users?  I am using parameterized SQL statements.

Comment: If you are using Azure, then Application Insights sounds like a much more suitable option.

Comment: I see Operational Insights but not Application Insights in my Azure Portal.  Do you know if this can be used with a standard Windows App (non Store App)?

Comment: Which portal? "Classic" or Preview? And yes, can be used with a Windows App. I have written sample console applications that send events.

Comment: Thanks, found it under Preview.  Looks very promising.